# user test not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

So this is my first time running test in rails and this is the error I'm getting.

Running:

E

> Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_show_post:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:26

E

> Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_update_post:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:36

E

> Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_create_post:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:18

E

> Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_post:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:41

E

> Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:13

E

> Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:8

E

> Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:31

E

> Error: UserTest#test_user_should_be_valid:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:8

E

Error:

> HomeControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
>
> bin/rails test test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:4

Finished in 0.316289s, 28.4550 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
9 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 9 errors, 0 skips

It is saying that the user table could not be found, why is that. heres my code.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user=User.new(name:"minhaj")
  end

  test "user should be valid" do
    assert @category.valid?
  end
end
```

## class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

```
 def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

## ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180413094453) do

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.string "address"
  end

  create_table "rsvps", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_rsvps_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_rsvps_on_user_id"
  end

# Could not dump table "users" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'false' for column 'admin_role'

end
```

Comment: In `assert @category.valid?` where does `@category` come from? And why isn't it `@user`?

Comment: your right I changed it but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on testing. It's always better than debugging. Try `rake db:test:prepare`.

Comment: I've tried that but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: And inside `rails/bin console` you can run `User.new(name: 'foo')` and it works, right?

Comment: No it didnt but when I changed it to User.new(email:"foo@hotmail.com") it worked on rails console. So I made the changes in my test so it says email instead of the name but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Someone suggested `bin/rails db:migrate` but deleted it. Try it, even though you are migrated. Then try (on `bash`) `RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:drop db:create`.

Comment: I followed what you said, however I'm still getting the same error as stated before.

Comment: Try (with MySQL) `bin/rails dbconsole --environment test`, then `show tables;`. Does your test database have any tables?

Comment: Does `# Could not dump table "users" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'false' for column 'admin_role'` have anything to do with it?

Comment: Maybe but how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: What kind of database do you have? Can you drop the database and migrate again to recreate it? Does `show tables;`, or the equivalent for your database, show what this `admin_role` is? You seem to be using Devise; did that create the `admin_role` field?